# SSIS package to load data to Salesforce using BULK API

Tags: ssis, salesforce, rest, script-task

I am using SSIS and trying to load object data to the Salesforce with REST API using Script Task, but the load request timeout in between without any error. I have to monitor the progress of the load and manually stop the job in case the data is not getting inserted and start again. I am trying to explore the option to use BULK API but not able to get the C# code which I can use in script task. Can someone suggest how to avoid the timeout error or use BULK API. Below is the code for reference:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(requestMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
string uri = sfServiceUrl + "/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Sales__c";
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
                
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + sfOauthToken);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
request.Content = content;
HttpResponseMessage response = await createClient.SendAsync(request);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about increating the timeout value.

Assuming your `createClient` object is of type [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0), there is a [Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_Timeout) property.

You can try to set the timeout to a bigger value, before you call `SendAsync`

For e.g., to have timeout of an hour, `createClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);`

Docs:

> The default value is 100,000 milliseconds (100 seconds).

> To set an infinite timeout, set the property value to InfiniteTimeSpan.